# I need to return multiple strings from a class

Tags: nsstring, return-value, objective-c-2.0

I have code in which the class in question gets data from a server, and parses it with the result being two strings. I need to return the two NSStrings but most tries have had issues because of the NSString type. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

return an array with the first string at index 0 and the second at index 1.